# WordPress sort by meta value

Tags: php, wordpress, events, post

I'm struggling with the following:
I have installed a plugin (Event Dates).
No I want events published on my homepage. I've got this for 99,9% working.
However the sorting doesn't work.

It sorts on publishong date but it needs to be sorted on event date.
The event date is in the wp_postmeta table but I can't get it to sort.

Here is a little more info:

```
<?php
$args=array(
'post_type' => 'tribe_events',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'posts_per_page' => 5,
'meta_key'   => '_EventStartDate',
'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
'order' => 'DESC');

$my_query = '';
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
<?php $key_2_value = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_EventStartDate', true); ?>
<?php echo '<div class="ex_agendapost_title">'.
                date_i18n( 'd F', strtotime( $key_2_value )   ).'</div>';?>
<div class="ex_agenda_event"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" 
         rel="bookmark" title="<?php   the_title_attribute(); ?>">
    <?php the_title(); ?> &raquo;</a></div>
<?php
endwhile;
}
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

It just won't sort.
Any ideas?

M.

Answer (score 0):

You can use orderby in WP_Query

```
$query = new WP_Query( array ( 'post_type' => 'product', 'orderby' => 'meta_value', 'meta_key' => 'price' ) );
```

[**Reference**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters)

Comment: How is this different then what I allready have? The only thing changed is the value of 'orderby'. This doesn't make any diferences

Comment: I need a way to sort on meta_value. When my data is saved to the db it has the following value e.g.:2014-06-11 08:00:00. So I want to 'orderby' => 2014-06-11 08:00:00

Comment: 'meta_key'   => '_EventStartDate',
'orderby' => 'you date comes here',
'order' => 'DESC'

Comment: Yeah that is what I'm trying to do but that doesn't work because my date is the 'orderby'=>'meta-value' of 'meta_key'=>'_EventStartDate'

Comment: do you try 'orderby' => 'date' will be same  as you providing the custom date

Comment: That didn't work but I also don't understand how that could work. Can you explain the idea behind this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that will show only future dated events and in date order (newest first)

You will have to change the field name and post type name though:

```
$currentDate = (int) date('Ymd');
$eventsResult = new WP_Query( array ( 'post_type' => 'event', 'post_status' => 'publish', 'posts_per_page' => '3', 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'meta_key' => 'event_date', 'order' => 'ASC', 'meta_query' => array( array( 'key' => 'event_date', 'value' => $currentDate, 'compare' => '>', 'type' => 'NUMERIC' ) ) ) );
```

Comment: Thnx I'll check it out.

Comment: I just kicked my own ass!!! This is embarrassing. It worked the entire time. I echo'ed the date without a year. So when I was filling the calander with dates I went as far as 2018. Because there is no year published I saw months in the order of nov, may, jan.... but that is because it's in different years. Sorry for wasting your time guys........